# how to convert a method with nested loops to IQueryable query via LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, loops, nested-loops

How to convert this method with nested loops to IQueryable query via LINQ ?
I want to have one database query. Below db-scheme, three classes: MyObject, Region and Link.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Region>> GetData()
{
    IEnumerable<Link> links = await Repositories.LinkDataDbSet.GetAllAsync();
    IEnumerable<Region> regions = await Repositories.PlacesDbSet.GetAllAsync();
    IEnumerable<MyObject> myObjects = await Repositories.MyObjectsDbSet.GetAllAsync();

    foreach (Region region in regions)
    {
        var linkObjects = new List<MyObject>();

        foreach (Link link in links.Where(r => r.regionId == region.id))
        {
            linkObjects.Add(myObjects.FirstOrDefault(r => r.id == link.objectId));
        }

        region.MyObjects = linkObjects;
    }

    return regions;
}

public class MyObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public int regionId { get; set; }
    public int objectId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: start by removing the self made limitation of an additional repository, and work with the context direct. Then you can use a `join`, and finallay an .select to make a nested object

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt i added db-scheme and one more condition. thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know which version of EF or .Net/Core you are using, but give something like this a try:

```
var regions = await (from place in Repositories.PlacesDbSet.AsQueryable()
                     join link in Repositories.LinkDataDbSet.AsQueryable() on place.id equals link.regionId
                     join obj in Repositories.MyObjectsDbSet.AsQueryable() on link.objectId equals obj.id  into objsSet
                     select new Region
                            {
                                 id = place.id,
                                 MyObjects = objsSet
                             }).ToListAsync();
```